# is there any maping from $S^1$ to $S^1$ of odd degree, which is not an odd function?

Tags: functions, algebraic-topology, even-and-odd-functions

I want to prove for every continous function from $s^n$ to $s^n$ of odd degree there exists $x$ such that $f(-x)=-f(x)$ so I used this "that the sum of two functions of odd degree must be odd" but I don't know if this is really true or not.
I just know that sum of two odd functions is odd but I don't think every function of odd degree has to be an odd function, so I'm trying to find an example for this using a function from $s^1$ to  $s^1$.
thanks for any help

Comment: Take a small perturbation around a given odd map.

Comment: I suggest putting those answers in the answer box, not in the comment box. The comment box is not for answers.

Comment: I think the sum of two odd degree functions is also of an odd degree but doesn't have to be an odd function... Am I right?

Comment: Besides spelling, punctuation, and capitalization, there are some ways this Question can be improved.  I'm confused by the notation.  The title asks about mappings on $S^1$, which is commonly the "one-sphere" (or circle), but the body of the Question introduces a notion of "functions of odd degree" which is not defined (and somewhat conflated with the notion of an odd function, also not clear in the context of a topological circle).

Answer (score 4):

$$(\cos\theta,\sin\theta) \mapsto (\cos(3\theta+\alpha), \sin(3\theta+\alpha)),$$
where $\alpha$ is some small angle, winds three times around the circle every time the argument to the function goes around once, but it's not an odd function.

$$
(\cos\theta,\sin\theta) \mapsto\left(\cos\left( 6\pi\left(\frac\theta{2\pi} \right)^2\right), \sin\left( 6\pi\left( \frac\theta{2\pi} \right)^2 \right) \right) \quad \text{for } 0\le\theta< 2\pi
$$
also winds around three times , but it's very far from being an odd function.